# How to not bundle server code when using Angular Universal with a NestJS Backend

Tags: angular, nestjs, typeorm, angular-universal

I have an Angular Universal application with a backend written in NestJS and I am trying to add TypeORM to my project. I run into problems when trying to run migrations because the output of my backend is a single main.js file. Is there a way to accomplish this?

My 'server' inside angular.json:

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "dist/<< PROJECTNAME >/server",
    "main": "server.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
    "externalDependencies": [
      "@nestjs/microservices",
      "@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module",
      "@nestjs/websockets",
      "@nestjs/websockets/socket-module",
      "cache-manager"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "optimization": false
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "outputHashing": "media",
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "sourceMap": false
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your architecture properly but I'd separate the Nest.js application completely or use a monorepo framework like [Nx](https://nx.dev) if you want to keep them in the same code repository.

[Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal) is a tool to render an Angular application on the server-side. It is not meant to run the whole backend solution.

Nest.js, even if it looks like Angular in its code and structure, is not Angular.